# Netbeans PHP - Code Navigator show included files

Tags: netbeans-7

Using Netbeans 7.2.1 can I get included files to show up in the "Navigator"?

In Dreamweaver they appear in the toolbar, in Aptana Studio 3 they appear in the "Outline", phpDesigner they appear as dependencies.

If I can get Netbeans to show php includes ( and even files linked link JS and CSS files ) I'm going to use it as my primary PHP IDE.